# How to use a background image larger then the visible area

Tags: html, css

I have a bg image width 1300px.

I create the #header container with the width: 100% background-image('image-bg') center; 
The content has 960px; margin: 0 auto; so that will always be in the center.

#header is in a #page container that has also 100% background-image('image-bg-border') center; just to create a nice border

But now when I resize the browser on small width values the #page, body, html is smaller then the content within #header or other element that has 960px; margin: 0 auto.

What to do that the #page to be at least the same width as #header when you resize it on small width?
Temp link: removed

EDIT: Look a the div#page while you resize the browser on the width on smaller values. The #header at one pint gets larger then #page, to see this scroll to the right on horizontal.

Comment: Sorry, the question is unclear. The page you link to gets a horizontal scrollbar if you make it narrower. Isn't that what you want? Then you should explain better.

Comment: When you resize a lot the the browser on width to small values the #page and #header should remain the same but the #page gets smaller. To see this resize browser a lot to small width, scroll on horizontal to right. Use something like google chrome, developer tools(obviously you know that, if not you could not help me)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The div#page does not have a width set, so it defaults to the width of the window. The header#branding inside it does have a min-width of 960px, therefore it will extend outside of the div#page area.

Do you want to have the div#page to have a min-width of 960 px, or do you want to try to restrict the whole page to the window width?

Comment: I completely missed that for div#page. I solved it. There is another problem when the same resize. If you scroll o the top while the browser is resized on small size the font gets a little smaller. Why?

Comment: @Alqin Sorry for taking so long to get back to you. Busy day. But you have `@media (max-width: 650px)` in your twentyeleven stylesheet, which reduces the font size on narrower screens.

Comment: Thats ok, thanks a lot for all the help. I still have a lot to learn.

Comment: Quick question. How I overwrite @media to go to default as it was never declared without altering the original style sheet where is include it?

Comment: @Alqin if you don't want to change the contents of that particular css file, just put another `@media (max-width:650px)` in another css file that gets included later, with the style properties that you want, for instance `font-size:medium` I think it was. If you make sure this gets loaded later, the browser will use this declaration instead of the original one.